# Examine the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm really stuck with my homework in real analysis. Could anyone give me some ideas/tips or solutions, how to get these following tasks done? I would be very thankful!

> The task is to examine the convergence of the following series:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k (\ln(k^2+2)-\ln k^2)\, \arctan(1-k^2).     $$

Comment: This looks like an alternating series.  What do you know about alternating series?  What happens when you apply that knowledge to this problem?

Comment: Hint: as $k$ grows, the $\arctan$ nears an horizontal asymptote, i.e. becomes quasi-constant.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but only some hints, as you requested.

First of all, note that as $k\to\infty$, the factor $\arctan(1-k^2)\to\cdots$, a finite but nonzero numerical limit. So from the point of view of series convergence, this factor is as good as a constant and won't affect the convergence or divergence of the series at all.

Then, using properties of logarithms, $\displaystyle \ln(k^2+2)-\ln k^2=\ln\left(\frac{k^2+2}{k^2}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{k^2}\right)\approx\frac{2}{k^2}$ as $k\to\infty$. This should be a strong hint at the behavior of this series. So to examine the original series for absolute convergence, take the absolute value of its terms and apply the Limit Comparison Test with $\sum\cdots.$